# How Can I turn off this tab toggle in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, tabs, productivity-power-tools

I am using MS Productivity Power Tools extension and have my tabs aligned vertically. I like to pin the files I am working more frequently, so they are at the top. However, recently when I debug my solution there is a toggle arrow section that appears.

If I do not toggle this arrow then all of the files that are not pinned are inaccessible and VS behaves very sporadic. I am guessing I must have hit some key combination that turned this on. I do not have this issue in all of my solutions.

Does anyone know how to turn this off, Google had not yielded any useful info so far.

[image: Picture of the tab toggle arrow for reference]